# Fullcalendar height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've integrated Fullcalendar on to the homepage of my site. Code is...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/XXXXXXXXimport.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
        currentTimezone: 'Europe/London' // an option!
    },

eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
            $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
        }
    }
    });
});

</script>
```

How do I adjust the overall height of the calendar's content? I've looked on this link...

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/

...and tried to follow the guide but I must be writing the code wrong because it won't work for me. I want to limit the height to 180px.

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Height option is expressed in pixels. Then you've to write height: 180 and not height: 180px. Maybe it is what you've done in your unsuccessful test?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked with fullCalendar before, but based on the link you pasted, this should work.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: {...},
  eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {...},
  height: 180
});
```

Just make sure this is the first time were you call the `fullCalendar` function. Otherwise you need to use: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 180);`

Might be a long shot, but other thing to keep in mind is your CSS, make sure it's not overriding the height of `#calendar`, watch for `!important`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with setting "height" and "contentHeight" parameters and figure out that in some cases they do not work(e.g. in my case events in the bottom of calendars were not clickable). So I ended up with setting "aspectRatio" parameter instead:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: {...},
  eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {...},
  aspectRatio: 1.15
});
```

which worked perfectly(obviously you need to calc you aspect ratio based on width of your calendar).